# NoSQL DB for Android other than MongoDB and CouchDB?

Tags: android, database, json, nosql

Is there any better `NoSQL DB` for `Android` other than CouchDB and MongoDB. **With couchdb the issue is its start-up time on Android devices, which take 5-10 seconds(is very high)**.

On the other hand I found **TouchDB** which is not yet mature enough to use, right now.

I want to store whole data in a **NoSQL DB in JSON format**(both online and on Android phone). I there any DB that has **start up time in milliseconds and stores data in JSON format**?

Comment: Sqlite is awesome on Android.

Comment: SQLite has its limitations. It is not that fast as NoSQL databases are. Also NoQSL databases allows the developers to understand and query data in their own way, which is good flexibility. Secondly, the issue is with online storage to SQLite data. How would I store it, I truly do not know right now?

Comment: MasterJ: can you specify more clearly what your requirements are? Which features do you need?

Comment: Hi  Mike Rhodes. I want to use NoSQL Database for storing data of Android app both on the phone and online, in JSON format. I want to use it because of the flexibility of querying data. 

1. Store data on phone.
2. Sync data online.
3. Using JSON or other flexible structure.

Comment: Is there anyone who can reopen this question?

Answer (score 3):

Two possible options are:

- [BerkeleyDB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/berkeleydb/overview/index-093405.html)
- [UnQLite](http://unqlite.org/)

Comment: Thanks.

Can you please clear only one more thing to me? Can I use these on Android phones? Is there any light version available for Mobile Phones?

Comment: The Java edition of Berkeley DB can be used on android, see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17277_02/html/HOWTO-Android.html . UnQLite should work also I think as it is built for Unix systems. There's also http://hamsterdb.com which supports mobile platforms.

Comment: Thanks Rotem. I will try to use it in my Project.

Comment: BerkeleyDB require a commercial license for closed sources apps while UnQLite is BSD licensed.

Answer (score 2):

you have many options, you can use [iBoxDB.java](https://github.com/iboxdb/forjava) if you're using java, or [iBoxDB for mono](https://iboxdb.codeplex.com/releases/view/111604) if using c#.
iBoxDB stores data in Map format, it is easily converted to JSON. iBoxDB includes Replication(example in Test.java), so if just want to doing Sync data, don't need JSON.